# Why does adding items into a blank array display the items repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, foreach, createelement

I want to take input value from the user then push that data to an array. Now the problem is when I am trying to create a new element for each object. For the first input, the table is all good but when I am trying to input for the second time the loop is printing the second object with the first object. I want to display it as index wise

Here is my code:

```js
const addMore = document.getElementById("pAdd");
const tForm = document.getElementById("t");
let table = document.getElementById("table")

let orders = []
addMore.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let order = {
    productName: document.getElementById("pName").value,
    productPrice: document.getElementById("pPrice").value,
    qty: document.getElementById("qty").value,
    total: document.getElementById("total").value,

  }
  // let orderObject= JSON.stringify(order)
  orders.push(order)
  tForm.reset();

  orders.forEach(allOrder => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr")
    Object.values(allOrder).forEach(text => {
      let cell = document.createElement("td")
      let texNode = document.createTextNode(text)
      cell.appendChild(texNode)
      row.appendChild(cell)
    })
    table.appendChild(row)
  })

  //let rightSdie = document.querySelector(".right")
  //rightSdie.appendChild(table)
})

function addNumber() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pPrice").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("qty").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var disc = document.getElementById("disc").value
  var discTotal = y * x * disc / 100;
  document.getElementById("total").value = (y * x) - z - discTotal;
}
```

```html
<form id="t">
<input id="pName" name="pName" type="text" placeholder="Products name">
        <input id="productId" name="productId" type="text" placeholder="Product id">
        <input id="pPrice" oninput= addNumber() name="pPrice" type="text" placeholder="Selling price">
        <input id="qty"  oninput= addNumber() type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="qty " size="4" pattern="" inputmode="" placeholder="qty">
        <input id="disc" oninput= addNumber() name="disc" type="text" placeholder="Discount:">
        <input id="amount" oninput= addNumber() name="amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount:">
        <input id="stock" name="stock" type="text" placeholder="stock:">
        <input id="total" name="total" type="text" placeholder="Total: " readonly>
        <button type="button" id="pAdd" class="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>OK</button>
        </form>

<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Please, check your code snippet. You need to create working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first input the table was all good because you were appending the same order every time within the `forEach`. In order to solve it, put it outside so that the next times it will print the current object typed. Also, you have to do configure a way to avoid the submition of empty forms.

Note that I needed to adapt your HTML creating a `<form>` and a `<table>`. Plus, commented some lines.

```js
const addMore = document.getElementById("pAdd");
const tForm = document.getElementById("t");
let table = document.getElementById("table")

let orders = []
addMore.addEventListener("click", function (e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let order = {
    productName: document.getElementById("pName").value,
    productPrice: document.getElementById("pPrice").value,
    qty: document.getElementById("qty").value,
    total: document.getElementById("total").value,
  }
  // let orderObject= JSON.stringify(order)
  orders.push(order)
  tForm.reset();
  
  let row; // this outsite forEach
  
  orders.forEach(allOrder => {
    row = document.createElement("tr")
    Object.values(allOrder).forEach(text => {
      let cell = document.createElement("td")
      let texNode = document.createTextNode(text)
      cell.appendChild(texNode)
      row.appendChild(cell)
    })
  })
  
  table.appendChild(row) // also this outside forEach
 
  //let rightSdie = document.querySelector(".right")
  //rightSdie.appendChild(table)
})


function addNumber() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pPrice").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("qty").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var disc = document.getElementById("disc").value
  var discTotal = y * x * disc / 100 ;
 document.getElementById("total").value = (y * x ) - z - discTotal;
}
```

```html
<form id="t">
<input id="pName" name="pName" type="text" placeholder="Products name">
        <input id="productId" name="productId" type="text" placeholder="Product id">
        <input id="pPrice" oninput= addNumber() name="pPrice" type="text" placeholder="Selling price">
        <input id="qty"  oninput= addNumber() type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="qty " size="4" pattern="" inputmode="" placeholder="qty">
        <input id="disc" oninput= addNumber() name="disc" type="text" placeholder="Discount:">
        <input id="amount" oninput= addNumber() name="amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount:">
        <input id="stock" name="stock" type="text" placeholder="stock:">
        <input id="total" name="total" type="text" placeholder="Total: " readonly>
        <button type="button" id="pAdd" class="add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>OK</button>
        </form>

<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly.